# What does Value="{Binding}" do?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF Binding Syntax Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502331/wpf-binding-syntax-question)

I've been using this syntax all over the place, and I thought I knew what it did, but now I have no idea.

```
Value="{Binding}"
```

I am having huge trouble searching for this syntax online because of course the curly brackets are ignored.

For instance:

```
<Style x:Key="GridCell" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding}}"/>
</Style>
```

When applied as a style to a textblock is binding the tooltip to the unfomatted (unconverted) property that the textblock content (text) is bound to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its data binding value to the root of the window or control's `DataContext`.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. Is there a way to explicitly bind to the DataContext of a control? What if you don't like what your parent set the data context to and you wanted to bind to the DataContext of your parent's parent?

Comment: I think that's beyond the scope of this question. You should ask another one about that.

Comment: I'm still confused. Binds to WHAT on the DataContext? Just some random property? Some "default" property? The entire DataContext object? If I have a FileInfo object as a DataContext, and I have a TextBlock, and I bind Text="{Binding}" what will be in the Text and why?

Answer (score 8):

It binds to the current Datacontext.

I suggest you take a look at the [WPF Databinding Cheat Sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf).  Should be a handy reference.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `{Binding <something>}` creates a new [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) using the [Binding markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413.aspx).

Specifically, `{Binding}` creates the `Binding` object with empty path. And since the paths are relative to the current `DataContext`, this means binding to it.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) refers to `{Binding}` as the "empty binding syntax". It binds the property to the entire object referenced by the DataContext.

It may be worth noting that a control inherits the DataContext of its parent element (unless you set it directly).

Answer (score 0):

It is how WPF links your data to the control. See MSDN for more detail. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: I'm not being 'Meta' here - I want to know exactly what using a plain empty binding is binding to.

Comment: sorry didn't know you were inquiring about empty binding or just asking the binding question in general. It appears the empty binding part is already answered, but as they say it just binds to current context if set.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends where in the your Element Tree you are using this. By default it means current `DataContext`. But if you are already inside your ListBox, then it means ListBox's DataContext. Which is different from Root/Main DataContext.